# Can posting an answer, in the absence of a specific disclaimer, on Law SE attract Hedley-Byrne liability?

Tags: england-and-wales, tort

If, as a barrister, I post answers on Law SE, without specific extra disclaimers other than the standard Law SE one, can such a posting give rise to a pure economic loss Hedley Byrne tort case against me should my advice lead someone astray (obviously I would hope this would never happen, but I’m a lawyer who has to think of worst case scenarios)?

Comment: Do England and Wales not have some sort of reasonableness standard for this sort of thing? Can a guy wearing a clown wig and rubber nose tell people to sell their stocks and invest in onions, or sue the queen for wearing funny hats, while riding a unicycle and juggling chainsaws, and attract such liability, if he's also technically a barrister, and somebody takes his advice? What reasonable person would believe free advice they get on the internet from an unverified source is coming from a lawyer acting in his professional capacity? Who'd even trust anybody here claiming to be a lawyer?

Comment: Holy cow. A lawyer seeking legal advice on Law.SE.

Answer (score 2):

### Such a suit is extremely unlikely to succeed

Hedley-Berne negligence requires a special or fiduciary relationship between the speaker and the listener. This Q&A forum is unlikely to provide that level of relationship.

Further, there is a disclaimer, which is the reef that Hedly-Berne foundered on, in the [contract](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#warranties) each user signed up to before they could post. It's repeated on every page if using a browser (but not if using the app), in the [tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour), and the [how to ask](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The user has been warned on multiple occasions that they are not getting legal advice.

Any such suit would almost certainly be summarily dismissed on application.